# MongoError: Invalid Operation, No operations in bulk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm unable to do bulk insert to mongo using mongoose.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Define our results schema
var webSchema = new Schema({"abc" : String},{
  collection: 'web_v2'
});

MyApi.prototype.Webs= mongoose.model('Webs', webSchema);

resultData = [{"abc": "12121221"},{"abc": "44545"},{"abc": "545"}]

MyApi.prototype.Webs.collection.insert(resultData, function (err, myDocuments) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("web inserted : " + myDocuments.result.n);
  }
});
```

I'm getting the following error

```
MongoError: Invalid Operation, No operations in bulk
at Function.MongoError.create (/pathtoapp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
at toError (/pathtoapp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:114:22)
at OrderedBulkOperation.execute (/pathtoapp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/ordered.js:500:11)
at bulkWrite (/pathtoapp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:582:8)
at Collection.insertMany (/pathtoapp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:477:44)
at Collection.insert (/pathtoapp/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:753:15)
at NativeCollection.(anonymous function) as insert (/pathtoapp/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:136:28)
at /pathtoapp/index.js:481:57
at /pathtoapp/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:721:13
at /pathtoapp/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
at async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/pathtoapp/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:236:30)
at _parallel (/pathtoapp/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:712:9)
at Object.async.parallel (/pathtoapp/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:726:9)
at /pathtoapp/index.js:479:43
at /pathtoapp/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:721:13
at /pathtoapp/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
```

anyone please let me know what am i doing wrong.?

Comment: anyone facing same problem..?

Comment: same problem I experience now, any updates??

Comment: `Web.collection.insert` is Mongo syntax, not Mongoose. I'm not sure why it's failing. But since you are using Mongoose, you can use `Webs.insertMany(resultData)`. [docs here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany)

Answer (score 39):

Most likely you are trying to insert an empty array.

Here is the [MongoDB Jira site reference to this error](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-975?focusedCommentId=1537673&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-1537673)

> This is probably caused by your last insertMany attempting to insert
>   an **empty array [ ]**. I suggest you insert a guard before
>   insertMany.

Comment: By the way don't Mongo allow inserting empty array?

Answer (score 6):

Just check if the bulk instance has operations before calling `execute` with this function:

```
const BulkHasOperations = (b) => b && b.s && b.s.currentBatch && b.s.currentBatch.operations && b.s.currentBatch.operations.length > 0;
...
const bulk = db.collection('something').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
...
BulkHasOperations(bulk) && bulk.execute();
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my check in a basic if block if you were using the raw MongoDB driver for Node js, it might help:

```
let col = dbContext.collection("collectionName");
let bulk = col.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

if(bulk && bulk.s && bulk.s.currentBatch 
&& bulk.s.currentBatch.operations 
&& bulk.s.currentBatch.operations.length > 0){
//execute operations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the array that you're passing to bulkWrite([...elements]).
The elements array **should not** be empty, all of its elements need to be an object, and the objects need to contain properties of operation type, filter and update field. They too CAN NOT be empty.